# Setting boolean variable when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I got some HTML like so of a Bootstrap checkbox. By default the checkbox is on.

```
    <div id="full" class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked=""> Include Full Classes
        </label>
    </div>
```

I have this jQuery which detects whether the item is checked or non-checked

```
        var full;
        $('#full').change(function(){
            if(this.checked)
            {
                full = true;
                console.log(full);
            } else {
                full = false;
                console.log(full);
            }
        });
```

What I want to achieve is, when the checkbox is selected, it would set `full` to 1, and if it is unselected, set `full` to 0.

I performed `console.log()` to the `full` variable, and in my output, all I got was `false`.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

This is the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933292/jquery-not-setting-variable-when-checkbox-is-checked) I am referencing

Comment: you should try `$(this).is(':checked')` instead of `this.checked`

Comment: @Sushil still appears to only say false. I was if the HTML `checked` has to do with it.

Comment: let me create a quick jsfiddle

Comment: i didn't notice that `full` was your div id. @maximillan's answer is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to give your checkbox its own ID so that you can determine whether it's checked. Right now you are testing whether the div is checked (which isn't possible) - what you want to do instead is check whether the `input` element is checked!

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
var full;
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
  full = this.checked;
  console.log(full);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="full" class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="">Include Full Classes
  </label>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qtczor1q/2/

Comment: How does a `div` have a `change` event?

Comment: @tymeJV I really don't know, to be honest. I changed OP's example a minimal amount until I got it working for the answer, and I'm just now going back over it for clarity / best practices. I just edited it to do a checkbox change event instead though, thanks for raising the question.

Comment: Yeah - I thought it was weird it worked... wonder if that checkbox change event bubbled up to the div?

Comment: @tymeJV Looks like it did bubble up. More info here: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Good to know - you can also use `this.checked` inside the `change` handler, rather than recreating the same selector :D. Or to really shorten it: `$('#checkbox').change(function() { full = this.checked; console.log(full); });`

Comment: @tymeJV That didn't occur to me, but is much more elegant! I've reduced the size of the example a lot by using your suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The output for `this.checked` is `boolean` should do the trick

```
var full;
$('#full').change(function(){
   full = this.checked  ? 1 : 0 ; 
   //or using jquery 
   // full = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
   console.log(full);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> First set all unchecked to false.

```
 var $checked = $(':checkbox');
    $checked.not(':checked').attr('value', 'false');
    $checked.change(function(){
        $clicked = $(this); 
        $clicked.attr('value', $clicked.is( ":checked" ));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#full')` isn't the checkbox, it's the `div`. You want to look at the checkbox *within* the div.

```js
var full;

var cb = $('#full input[type=checkbox]');

cb.change(function() {
  if (cb.prop('checked')) {
    full = true;
    console.log(full);
  } else {
    full = false;
    console.log(full);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="full" class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="">Include Full Classes
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `if` statement looks like overkill to me. As @joyBlanks has correctly pointed out, if what you're looking for is true or false then `this.checked` is all you need. But if you want 1 or 0 then use the ternary operator.

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    console.log( this.checked ); //true or false
    console.log( this.checked ? 1 : 0 ); //1 or 0
})
//trigger change event when the page loads -- checkbox is checked when page loads
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="full" class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked=""> Include Full Classes
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would honestly just not use JQuery. Just do it simple.

```
document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked;
```

If you do not need to use JQuery, just use this variable.